# PhpStorm live edit with less files

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I'm using PhpStorm with Live Edit.

Problem is that it's not updating when I change `less` files.

My `less` files are compiled to `css` by `gulp`.
I don't want to use File Watcher because it compiles all `less` files and I need to compile only one file `app.less` and watch all less files. I know how to do it with `gulp` but not how to do it with File Watchers.

Is there a solution that Live Edit will watch `less` or `css` files without edit?

Comment: *"I don't want to use File Watcher because it compiles all less files and I need to compile only one file app.less and watch all less files."* So ... why don't you do that with File Watchers? It works (I'm using it just fine).

Comment: If you want to use (to try at least) File Watchers for `.less` files -- please show a screenshot of your File Watcher

Comment: I can use File Watchers but I simply don't know how :| I've got standard `less` watcher configuration

Comment: That's what I'm using: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5sxO.png (P.S. I'm keeping my `.less` files in `/assets/less/` folder and compiled files in `/assets/css/` -- hence the `../css/` part in file output paths). I have like 14 partials/includes files -- if I edit any of them then only my main file will be compiled: http://postimg.org/image/i9oeeyz53/

Comment: P.S. If that would still not work (for whatever reason) you can always hardcode input/output file name .. so it will only compile your `app.less` instead of partial/included files.

Comment: FYI: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Watchers+in+PhpStorm

Comment: **BTW** -- your problem may actually be this one which does not seem to depend on how you compile your CSS files... -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12926

Comment: This can be bug in my situation because `synchronize` method also not working

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with compiling scss files using gulp, namely the files in the IDE don't auto-update if they're changed via a task fired from a gulp.watch process (glitch dunno what jetbrains is doing about it).

There are 2 ways to get the files to update within the IDE:

- File > Synchronize
- Manually collapse and expand the tree in the project view

My hacky way to solve this problem is to macro the save process in phpstorm i.e.

1. Start macro record
2. File > Save All
3. File > Synchronize
4. File > Synchronize
5. File > Synchronize
6. Stop macro record

The Synchronize functionality is a little glitchy but i've found doing it 2 or 3 times inside the macro seems to work.

You can then rebind `ctrl + s` to your new macro and it should work.

Comment: *"(glitch dunno what jetbrains is doing about it)"* There is no glitch here. Gulp watcher is an external process and can compile file at any time (e.g. file modified/generated by some background/scheduled task which IDE knows nothing about). IDE only checks for external changes only on frame activation (e.g. on Alt+Tab). For other cases -- manual "File | Synchronize". So yes -- your solution is a reasonable way if you are using external automatic compilation.

Comment: *"The Synchronize functionality is a little glitchy but i've found doing it 2 or 3 times inside the macro seems to work."* I would not say so. The compilation by your gulp watcher requires some time (it does not take 0.0sec, right?) + gulp watcher needs to detect actual file modification as well (small .. but still some delay). Because of all these delays .. the first 1 or 2 executions of "File | Synchronize" simply does not see any changes yet.

Comment: Right you would not say so... well i would after 5 hours of testing many different solutions yesterday. Even if i have gulp running and make a change and then manually sync after, sometimes the change isnt reflected.
Furthermore since you can't add any preset time delay to your macro's (as far as im aware) this is the only way to do it so you can automate to one or 2 keystrokes.